# how to save echo value in a function

Tags: php, arrays, function, echo

so i want to get echo value in a function and i want to use the value outside the function.
this is the function

```
function boyer_moore($pattern, $text)
{
   $n = strlen($text);
   $m = strlen($pattern);
   $goodSuffixes    = array();
   $badCharacters   = array();

   goodSuffixes($pattern, $goodSuffixes);
   badCharacters($pattern, $badCharacters);
   $j = 0;
   while ($j < $n - $m) {
      for ($i = $m - 1; $i >= 0 && $pattern[$i] == $text[$i + $j]; $i--);
      if ($i < 0) {
          echo $j;
          $j += $goodSuffixes[0];
      } else {
         $j += max($goodSuffixes[$i], $badCharacters[$text[$i + $j]] - $m + $i + 1);
      }
     }}
```

i want to use the value **echo $j** outside the function and save it in a variable.
i am still beginner.
please help me, thankyou before.

i want to accumulate all echo $j values. 
if i use return $j after the loop, the value will be different. Thankyou before.

Comment: but `$j` value can be changed in loop many times. You should elaborate whether you need to obtain the last `$j` value OR accumulate all `$j` values

Comment: Push `$j` values to array, return the array from the function

Comment: `$j` is a count. are you wanting to return the final count? add return $j after the loop

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i want to accumulate all $j values

Comment: @Hery, you can pass in an argument to the function (an empty array) or use `global ` keyword to fill a global array inside the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echo prints to STDOUT. return your variable, or set it as a class variable, or a global variable - so you can use it out your function

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do a little reading on how to use functions and their values.
Meanwhile, keep your code as it is, for now, just replace `echo` with `return`.

Then you can use the function like this:

```
$my_pattern = //some pattern
$my_text = //some text
$my_outside_the_function_variable = boyer_moore($my_pattern, $my_text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi at the end of your function use `return $j`, or declare $j as a global variable. So that you can use it every where in your page.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what `$pattern` or `$text` are suppose to be but to answer your question with the information you have provided you need to return `$j` from the function then echo it after the call to `boyer_moore()`

```
<?php

function boyer_moore($pattern, $text)
{
    $n = strlen($text);
    $m = strlen($pattern);
    $goodSuffixes = array();
    $badCharacters = array();

    goodSuffixes($pattern, $goodSuffixes);
    badCharacters($pattern, $badCharacters);
    $j = 0;
    while ($j < $n - $m) {
        for ($i = $m - 1; $i >= 0 && $pattern[$i] == $text[$i + $j]; $i--)
            ;
        if ($i < 0) {
            $j += $goodSuffixes[0];
        } else {
            $j += max($goodSuffixes[$i], $badCharacters[$text[$i + $j]] - $m + $i + 1);
        }
    }
    return $j;
}

...
...
$j = booyer_moore($pattern, $text);
echo $j;
```